# express JS - Can't managed to receive GET responses from other external servers to my view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, frontend

I've already tried almost every solution from the network regarding this common problem but didn't manage to solve this in my case.

Actually the GET request sent ok and return with response but the browser doesn't pass the response data to the view and present CORS error message in the console log:

*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8033' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

**My express server code -**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var fetch = require('fetch-cookie')(require('node-fetch'));
var btoa = require('btoa');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var cmd = require('node-cmd');
var reload = require('reload');
var sleep = require('sleep');

// Allow requests from the ui
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // TODO: Make specific
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
});

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.use(cors());

// app.set(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
//     $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
// }]);

// app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
//     res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
// });

var server = http.createServer(app);

// Reload code here
reload(app);

app.listen(8033, function () {
    console.log('Dashboard server is running and listening on port 8033');
});
```

The request details + response *(the response there is wrong, it should contains JSON with data, it works ok by postman)*

[image: Request details from the network pane]

[image: Response data from the network pane (wrong response)]

Comment: add OPTIONS: `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');`

Comment: Please go into the Network pane of your browser devtools and reload and then examine all the requests and responses that show there and copy the details — including the HTTP status codes for each — and then edit/update your question and paste those in. Also please updated the question to show the relevant part of your frontend JavaScript code that shows the code for the request you’re making which results in that error message cited in the question.

Comment: You've configured CORS on the wrong server. The CORS request is hitting 22999, not 8033.

Comment: @skirtle Thanks a lot buddy. what should I need to change in my server file?  I'm kind of new with these things.. :/

Comment: There is nothing you can do in the code for the server on port 8033 to make this work, it needs a code change to the server running on port 22999. If you aren't able to change the code for that server then you could try proxying requests via 8033 instead of using CORS.

Comment: @skirtle Yes I see.. I don't have access to port 22999, How can I proxying my server 8033? can I do it by using the npm -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and remove previous cors code in your file. Hope it works

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8033',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT',
    allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
    credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Still the same.. doesn't handle the CORS issue.. It's managed to render my response to the view only when I add "mode: no-cors" in the request header but it return status "0" instead of the real status

Comment: Note that you also need to pass `withCredentials: true` in the request options while doing this. If you have missed it please try that. This solution worked in my case.

Comment: Nop.. nothing help.. it's a pandora box.. not really can't handle it by cors npm.. I think the only chance to solve this is by proxy.. but i'm not familiar with this world..

Comment: you have configured wrong cors i guess as seen in the image and comments. try changing `origin: 'http://localhost:8033',` to `origin: '<your domain>:22999',` in my solution.

Comment: still the same error.. I'll try the nginx solution..  thanks